# Get a property value for every object in a list without using a foreach loop using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get the value of a property of every member of a collection in PowerShell **without using a Foreach** loop?

For example, a directory with these entries:

```
$items

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                      
-a----        3/11/2023   6:08 AM             16 file1.txt                                                                 
-a----        3/11/2023   6:08 AM             28 file2.txt                                                                 
-a----        3/11/2023   6:08 AM             34 file3.txt
```

The only way I've figured out to get each object's `length` property:

```
Foreach($i in $items)
{
    $i.Length
}
```

Is there another way to get the `length` property from each object without using a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Have you tried $items.Length?

Comment: That just gives how many items there are.

Comment: So to understand properly, you want to return the lenght property for each item. Correct? Try ```$items = GCI
$items | Select Length
```

Comment: Loops are either replicated or implicit.  There is no avoiding them when one needs to iterate over objects. As ' 
Reddy Lutonadio' points you to, is an implicit ForLoop. You could just shorten that to ```(Get-ChildItem-Path 'D:\Temp').Length``` as well. If you are just trying to shorten your code, then what has been proposed this far is prudent, but it's still looping. If you want more property names and/or than one property, then the ```Select-Object -Property``` is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you can use [select-object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html) and specify the name of the property from each object with a header column of `length` and a result for each object in `bytes`.

```
$items | Select-Object Length;
```

#### Output

```
Length
------
 26190
  5130
  8100
```

---

You can also select the specific property value(s) from an array object defined with properties by using a [calculated property](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) with an defined expression for the the result you seek without the need to put it through a `foreach` loop.

This PowerShell example will select the length property value from each object in kilobytes.

```
$items | Select-Object @{Name="KBytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1KB ) }};
```

#### Output

```
KBytes
------
26    
5     
8
```

This Powershell example will select the length property value from each object in bytes.

```
$items | Select-Object @{Name="Bytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1 ) }};
```

#### Output

```
Bytes 
----- 
26,190
5,130 
8,100
```

This PowerShell also selects the length property, but is also pipes it through [measure-object](https://ss64.com/ps/measure-object.html) to give you the specific bytes or kilobyte of each object.

```
$items | Select-Object @{N="Bytes"; E={ ($_ | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1 } };
```

#### Output

```
Bytes
-----
26190
 5130
 8100
```

```
$items | Select-Object @{N="KBytes"; E={ ($_ | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1KB } };
```

#### Output

```
      KBytes
      ------
25.576171875
 5.009765625
  7.9101562
```

---

**Lastly (and optionally)** for a shorter form syntax that may help simplify the logic if that's the main goal that use a [foreach method](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-method.html) loop but with less lines of code.

```
$items.Foreach({$_.Length});
```

#### Output (in bytes)

```
26190
5130
8100
```

---

## Supporting Resources

- [Select-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)
- [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)
- [ForEach Method](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-method.html)
- [Measure-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/measure-object.html)

Comment: Accepted because `Select-Object` seems to me to be the closest to a traditional python style `.map` approach

Answer (score 1):

One more implicit FOrEach -- pipe the collection through a [*filter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.3#filters):

```
Filter ItemSize {$_.Length}

$Items = gci -af

$Items | ItemSize
```

OUtput:

```
PS > Filter ItemSize {$_.Length}
>>
>> $Items = gci -af
>>
>> $Items | ItemSize
3764
3764
2256896
46
42326
46
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment. The ```[0]``, just mean get the first item.

```
Clear-Host
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File)[0] 
# Results
<#
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ---- 
-a----         23-Mar-21     13:28         395347 (MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.zip 
#>

Clear-Host
((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File)[0]).Length
# Results
<#
395347
#>


$Properties = @(
'Mode',
'LastWriteTime',
'Length', 
'Name'
)
$Properteis.Count

Clear-Host
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File)[0] | 
Select-Object -Property $Properties

# Results
<#
Mode   LastWriteTime      Length Name                                     
----   -------------      ------ ----                                     
-a---- 23-Mar-21 13:28:51 395347 (MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.zip
#>
```